# Qt: renaming variables crashes GUI

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, visual-studio-2015

After I innocently renamed an array, my formerly working solution still compiles and links, but the resulting binary (whether debug or release) now crashes after drawing the frame for the Qt GUI.

That is, renaming:

```
Mat map_x[NUM_PROJS];
```

to:

```
Mat mapX[NUM_PROJS];
```

...causes the resulting binary to crash.

As you might guess, the array has nothing to do with the GUI.  In fact, *this declaration is the only mention of this variable in the solution.*

I'm compiling my C++ code in Visual Studio 2015 using the Qt VS Add-In and Qt Creator to edit the user interface.

I figured that VS wasn't updating the .moc for the relevant source file, but I confirmed that 'Rebuild' is doing what it says by looking at the date stamps for the files (see below).

Following @JeremyFriesner's suggestion, in the debugger I confirmed the array is on the heap and has an enormous number of flags, as shown:

```
map_x 0x00007ff687d559c0 {{flags=1124007936 dims=0 rows=0 ...}, {flags=1124007936 dims=0 rows=0 ...}, {flags=...}, ...} cv::Mat[9]
```

The identical 'map_y' declaration shows 0 flags on the heap:

```
map_y   0x00007ff687d54ba0 {{flags=0 dims=0 rows=0 ...}, {flags=0 dims=0 rows=0 ...}, {flags=0 dims=0 rows=0 ...}, ...} cv::Mat[9]
```

After running QMake manually on a .pro file output from the VS2015 'Qt VS Tools' Add In, and recompiling in Qt Creator, the problem vanished momentarily, then reasserted itself after another clean/build cycle.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

VS build output follows:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: imageSlice_Qt, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Moc'ing imageSlice_Qt.h...
1>  Uic'ing imageSlice_Qt.ui...
1>  Moc'ing customSpinBox.h...
1>  Rcc'ing imageSlice_Qt.qrc...
1>  customSpinBox.cpp
1>  moc_customSpinBox.cpp
1>  moc_imageSlice_Qt.cpp
1>  imageSlice_Qt.cpp
1>  main.cpp
1>  utilities.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  qrc_imageSlice_Qt.cpp
```

Comment: did you try run qmake before rebuilding ?

Comment: What happens if you rename it to mapQ ?  Or map_q?  (i.e. is there something special about mapX in particular that causes the crash, or does it crash for other names also?)

Comment: Also, is this array on the stack on on the heap?  If it's on the stack, what is the value of sizeof(mapX) ?  If it's very big, it might be leading to a stack overflow and therefore some stack corruption with unintuitive results.

Comment: Try to remove all generated files (`moc_`, `*.obj`, etc) manually before rebuilding.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner, a) yes, I ran QMake before rebuilding, b) renaming to *any* other name (or deleting) also produces the same result.

Comment: Thanks @putu, I tried your suggestion and removed the 'GeneratedFiles' tree.  After rebuilding the same crash persists (and nothing caught by the debugger in VS)...

Comment: @H.G, if you post your comment as an answer I'll gratefully accept it.  It took a few cycles of rebuilding via QMake from the '.pro' project file generated by the 'Qt VS Tools' Add-In (it seems Visual Studio and Qt Creator may fight over open file handles?), but your approach eventually worked to halt the heap corruption.  The remaining mystery (for me) is what difference there is between calling QMake via VS or Qt Creator.  They should be equivalent, and seem to be in terms of compiler output.  I can't explain the difference between compiling the Qt project in VS via the Add-In.

Comment: @H.G -- I spoke too soon.  Now the same heap error noted above is happening after running QMake from Qt Creator, just as in VS...

Comment: I see. Without looking to actual project files, I think it's hard to figure out why it crashes. Did you try to run the debugger (maybe step-by-step execution)?

Comment: @putu, I did run in the VS debugger from breakpoint to breakpoint in order to fence the exception, but am not getting any useful results.

Comment: Are you really sure that renaming the variable is the cause? Anyway, rebuild might just not be enough, delete the whole folder that you build the project into. Sometimes that can help.